# Retrofit JSON parsing - how to detect if data field exists?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

REST API I am using returns JSON with data so I can parse them. Problem is that if some value is 0, API will not return such field at all. I need to find the way how to detect this in code.

JSON without data field:

```
current 
 dt 1611128505
 sunrise    1611125437
 sunset 1611156927
 temp   2.88
etc
```

JSON with data field:

```
current 
  dt    1611128505
  sunrise   1611125437
  sunset    1611156927
  temp  2.88
  precip 1.5 <---here
 etc
```

How do detect if data exists ?

```
 Call<RetrofitWeatherPOJO> call = apiInterface.doGetWeather(Lat, Lon, ApiKey, units);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RetrofitWeatherPOJO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RetrofitWeatherPOJO> call, Response<RetrofitWeatherPOJO> response) {

    RetrofitWeatherPOJO weatherPOJO = response.body();

    double TempCurrent = weatherPOJO.current.temp;
    double HumCurrent = weatherPOJO.current.humidity;
    double PrercipCurrent = weatherPOJO.current.precipitation; <-- will crash if JSON missing data
```

my gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

POJO class

```
  @SerializedName("precipitation")
  @Expose
  public Double precipitation;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a simple try catch to handle the exception and avoid crashes,
but a better way would be to use a simple if command if to check if the json is null or not like so

```
if (weatherPOJO.current.precipitation != null) {
                //do your thing
        
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, I thought I already tryied that .. thanks man

Comment: your welcome, if it helped you, could you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it won't crash, if you are using `gson` for serialisation it will ignore `null` values or missing fields , hence the field/parameter `precipitation` should have default value.

Comment: thanks, I added my gradle to original question, how to verify default value you mentioned? thanks